# How to Save Web page as html file using C# in UWP?

Tags: c#, html, uwp

I was working on a uwp project which uses webview to display webpages. I want to save a webpage locally from a url. I tried few these [how to save the webpage using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439775/how-to-save-the-webpage-using-c)

But it doesn't seem to be working as the solution is for a basic windows form app.

Please, forgive if I made any mistake asking question as I'm totally new to stackoverflow.

Comment: *"it doesn't seem to be working"* is not a problem statement.

Comment: its a typo, sorry. I tried those examples and they are not working. Any help?

Comment: *"they are not working"* is not a problem statement either. A developer knows what a problem statement is.

Comment: I'm not a developer, I'm just a student. And don't comment anything if you don't know the answer, please.

Comment: Stack Overflow wants answerable questions. *"It doesn't work"* is not. The fact that I don't know the answer doesn't matter. What does is that **no one** has an answer. Also, when new, it helps to take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to save a webpage locally from a url.

It is similar to windows form. Try to send get request to the URL, and get the  buffer or HTML content. For sending get request, you could use [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/httpclient). And then save the html buffer to a local file which format is `.html`. For example:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
var result = await httpclient.GetBufferAsync(new Uri("https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/"));
StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("test2.html", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(file, result);
```

After downloaded you may find the downloaded file in `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Packages\{PackageId}\LocalState`.

For more details about file operations please reference [Files, folders, and libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/).

Comment: thanks for a great explanation, but how am I suppose to get the original filename of the file that I'm downloading?

Comment: @VivekVaishya, didn't you download a webpage? What's the name of webpage? If I misunderstand you, please detail it.

Comment: yeah, your method worked for downloading webpage. now I'm trying to download small files like picture but i need to have original name of the picture. I tried this method over msdn -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounddownloader . but an exception is shown at HandleDownloadAsync(download, true); line

Comment: Wu, it was my mistake. I was looking at the code samples given over MSDN and was trying to implement my own methods. I forgot to implement HandleDownloadAsync() method what was giving me error.